# Parsing a text file, based on words count

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, comparator

I'm having trouble parsing a given text file based on words count frequency. Everything is happening accordingly except ordering, based on words count.

**My Approach**

- Parsing the text file
- Splitting & Storing every words in a String Array
- passed array will have the count for every unique word and passed to Map
- and Map will sort this based on Value

Here is the code:

```
public class TestApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String Line = null;
        Map<String, Integer> finalMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        FileParser parser = new FileParser();
        Reader fileReader = new FileReader("E:\\21350.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while ((Line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] str = Line.split("\\s");
            finalMap = parser.parseFile(str);
        }
        // new TestApp().showEntry(finalMap); // Before
        parser.sortByValue(finalMap);
        new TestApp().showEntry(finalMap); // After

        bufferReader.close();
    }

    public void showEntry(Map<String, Integer> map) {

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " --> " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    }

    public class FileParser {

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public Map<String, Integer> parseFile(String[] strArray) {
        for (String key : strArray) {
            int counter = 1;
            if (map.containsKey(key))
                map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
            else
                map.put(key, counter);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> sortByValue(Map<String, Integer> map) {

        List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {

            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                int x = (Integer) ((Map.Entry) o1).getValue();
                int y = (Integer) ((Map.Entry) o2).getValue();

                if (x > y)
                    return -1;
                else if (x < y)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        });

        Map<String, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

        Iterator it = list.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

*Whats wrong with this code?*

Comment: Consider using lower case name for you variables (i.e. line instead of Line)

Comment: Consider indenting properly, it is currently difficult to read.

Comment: You got the results for `Comparator.compare` backwards, I think.

Comment: @gpgekko ordering(Asc/Desc) isn't happening at all.

Comment: Thanks for indentation :)

Comment: You're replacing your `finalMap` at each loop turn (in your main method's `while`), do you want that?

Comment: @DaniloMuñoz: The code was mangled by your edit; half of the comparator is gone.

Comment: your `parseFile` method should take the `Map` as parameter, OR you can have a field in `FileParser` which you modify in `parseFile` (as you do now) but don't return it each time you parse one line, use a getter.

Comment: @AaronDigulla when editing, it shows correctly. I don't know how to solve it. Maybe a bug?

Comment: @DaniloMuñoz: Don't use `<code><pre>` to format code; it gets confused when the code contains `<`. Instead select the code and use the "code" button in the toolbar of the editor.

Comment: @DaniloMuñoz now i understand the, why formatting were not happened. Thx for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parser.sortByValue(finalMap);` returns a new (sorted) map which you ignore. Instead, you print the old (unsorted) `finalMap`.

```
finalMap = parser.sortByValue(finalMap);
```

should fix this.

Also note that the code above creates one map per file but prints only the last one of all of them.

Depending on what you want, you should either pass the map into `parser.parseFile(str);` to accumulate the results for all files or sort+print inside the loop to get one result per file.

Comment: Thx Aaron.. for the fix and Suggesion